# User Authentication Across Subdomains on Localhost

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-4

I'm building an app on my localhost. When I login via one subdomain, (e.g. sub.localhost/) I need to access that logged-in user with Auth:: in all other subdomains of my application (e.g. sub2.localhost/, sub3.localhost/).

I made the change as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22284173/laravel-4-authentication-not-working-with-subdomains) post suggests in config/session.php:

```
'domain' => '.localhost/',
```

No beans. In fact now I can't log in at all. Does this only work with a non-localhost domain? That would suck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try with only .localhost instead of .localhost/

if it is still doesn't work you can create an other host pointing to 127.0.0.1 : edit the /etc/hosts or Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts to set an other hostname for example : 127.0.0.1 host.loc

Comment: Yes. Tried `.localhost` as well. Same result. I'll try `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: I just now understood the 2nd part of your answer. That worked! Here's what I did: edit hosts file in Windows\System32\drivers\etc\ to redirect to a fake url `127.0.0.1      fakeurl.com`. Then of course I also added that following code to httpd-vhosts.conf file: `<VirtualHost *:80>DocumentRoot "/path/to/my/laravel/app"ServerName sub1.fakeurl.com</VirtualHost>`. I did this for each of my subdomains. Finally I restarted my server and it works great! I'm going to edit your answer to include everything to change... it's hard to read here.