# Laravel 4.2 User Authentication Across Subdomains on Server

Tags: authentication, laravel, wildcard-subdomain

Authentication persists nicely across my subdomains on my localhost thanks to help I received [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24214375/user-authentication-across-subdomains-on-localhost). But now I'm having trouble my remote server. I changed `'domain' => '.mydomain.com',` in `session.php` and now I can't log in at all. Actually, `Auth:attempt()` works just fine but it fails my `auth` filter when it then attempts to load the next page. Here's the code in my filter:

```
if ( Auth::guest() ) return Redirect::guest('login');
```

To me this means that sessions aren't working at all. And that line that I changed in `session.php` is definitely the culprit, because when I change it back to `'domain' => null,` I can log in just fine... it just doesn't persist across subdomains. Any ideas on getting laravel to remember sessions across my subdomains?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do all of this login testing in private windows, as old persisting cookies can really screw you up.

Comment: This worked. Deleted my browser cache and it works perfectly. And I thought this was going to be a complex solution. Thanks!