# How to use sub-domain routing in laravel 5.1 running on localhost :8000?

Tags: routes, subdomain, laravel-5.1

I am trying to learn sub-domain routing using laravel 5.1 running on localhost:8000.

I found different content on this topic but every one focused on application which are running on real web server.

here is one of them [sub domain routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21326980/how-to-use-the-laravel-subdomain-routing-function)

How can i do this on local environment?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this
edit hosts file in Windows\System32\drivers\etc\ to redirect to a fake url 127.0.0.1 fakeurl.com
httpd-vhosts.conf file: DocumentRoot "/path/to/my/laravel/app"ServerName sub1.fakeurl.com
then restart your server
Answer Source:
[User Authentication Across Subdomains on Localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24214375/user-authentication-across-subdomains-on-localhost)